# How to use information schema to get table result where select * is not allowed

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, information-schema

Consider table A with following schema,

> id | city | name
>
> 1 | xyz   | A
>
> 2 | pqr   | B

Query is not allowed with * like `SELECT * from table A`

But It is fine if we specify `SELECT id,city,name from table A`

So to solve this I did following,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',') FROM information_schema.columns where table_name='A' LIMIT 1;
```

result: `id,city,name`

Tried something like,

```
    SELECT (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',') FROM information_schema.columns where table_name='A' LIMIT 1
           )
     FROM table A;
```

But it does not work,
any other way I can achieve this?
PS: table columns in above example are less but there are tables with more than 25-30 columns then, in that case, it is difficult to get each column name from a schema and add manually in select query.

Comment: Are you asking about HTML tables or SQL tables?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` can't be used to create the `SELECT` columns! This function concat values of a column to one string on a group of rows (created by `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use `SELECT *`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could not find better option to add a table in question, so tried adding html, I thought it will render in question, but it did not. changed to space separated texts.

Comment: @sjdaws Let's not discuss why I am not allowed to use * in sql, Consider due to security/performance concerns.

Comment: @dkb it seems like it'd require an extra lookup and therefore be less efficient then simply selecting * which is why I was asking.

Comment: @sjdaws - you should avoid using `*` on `SELECT` because the amount of data you don't need. You should only select the columns you need. In his case `*` and `id,city,name` is the same but if later the table get a new column on `*` you get the additional column you don't need.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch he is doing a select * by proxy by getting all the column names from information schema, I understand not selecting information you don't need but what he is trying to achieve will always select all columns.

Comment: @sjdaws, I may remove some of the columns from select, but that is not the question, Let's stick with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a prepared statement and variables to get this working.

To get the columns you'll need to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, this automatically separates by commas, passing the second parameter as a comma will cause your fields to be separated by two commas:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database() AND TABLE_NAME ='A';

--- id,city,name
```

You can use `SELECT ... INTO` to put this query into a variable:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database() AND TABLE_NAME ='A' INTO @columns;
```

The variable `@columns` will now hold the column names:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @columns;
+--------------+
| @columns     |
+--------------+
| id,city,name |
+--------------+
```

Once you have the columns you'll need to construct the query

```
MariaDB [test]> SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @columns, ' FROM A');
```

You can verify the query looks right by selecting `@query`:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @query;
+----------------------------+
| @query                     |
+----------------------------+
| SELECT id,city,name FROM A |
+----------------------------+
```

Once you're happy with the query, prepare a statement and execute it:

```
MariaDB [test]> PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
MariaDB [test]> EXECUTE stmt;
+----+------+------+
| id | city | name |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | xyz  | A    |
|  2 | pqr  | B    |
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: I already got that result as you see in my question, result: id,city,name, What I want is to use this result in select query as mention above.

Comment: Right, I missed the actual question, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following query restrictions are the reason I had asked this question and I fond minor tweaked version of [sequelpro](https://github.com/aksonuabhay/sequelpro) which works for following restrictions:

1. A query should not be used without where clause

   select * from A;

   will become

   select id, city, name from A where 1;
2. A query should not have default select all column (*), all column must be specified in a query

   This will fail

   select id, city, name from A;

   It should be

   select id, city, name from A where 1;

   select id, city, name from A where city = 'abc';
3. Certain column/s should not be part of the query (if there are read level restrictions in place for column/s then the following query will fail(here A.name column))

   select id, city, name from A where 1;

So add exempted columns name to an editor by adding an entry in

> preferences --> tables --> filter column csv

text box as shown below.

If there are multiple columns which should not be part of query then add them as comma separated as shown below

> name,city

[image]

Now wherever you check content of table by clicking on Content tab of editor,
[image] editor will take care of all above restrictions

it works!